# Unable to launch Android application in Eclipse; An internal error occurred during: “Launching myApp” - run configuration target is empty

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm unable to start up my Android application in Eclipse, I'm getting the following error when I select "Run as Android Application"
When I try to "Run as Application" I get the following popup from eclipse

An internal error occurred during: "Launching myApp".

I check the run confuguration window and see that the target tab is empty! 
(it's worked before and I worked with real device)
What to do?
[image]

Comment: Cry, uninstall eclipse, restart your computer, install eclipse, try again. If it still doesn't work, download Android Studio. No, but seriously, eclipse does some weird things. Go to the Eclipse preferences pane and hit the Android tab. Make sure the SDK Location is pointing to the right folder.

Comment: after restart eclipse and updating what it say it's solved! thanks!!